# Opencart logout link was not shown in journal theme after logged in

Tags: opencart

I upgraded theme journal from 1.8.2 to 2.1 and the text “Welcome visitor…..” with login and register links disappeared. I can do my own in secondary menu, but then when I login, it will not change to name and logout link. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Journal > Menus > Secondary Menu` and in `Link` use **Opencart Page** & **Login (Account)** to display the **name** when logged in and **Opencart Page** & **Register (Logout)** to display the **logout** link.

Also have a look at the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mqUX.jpg